# Quantify how correct guesses about values in a time series are

Tags: time-series, accuracy

Let's say I have a simple dataset of unemployment numbers over time for a certain country:

```
[10, 9.5, 8, 7.5, 8.3, 7, 6.8]
```

And now a person makes a guess for each time period:

```
[12, 14, 10, 15, 14, 12, 8]
```

What would be a an appropriate way to quantify the "correctness" of the guess?

I'm guessing I should use Z-scores in some way, but I don't know how to apply them when it doesn't make sense to speak of **one** population mean (the correct number changing each year). Also, the method needs to "scale" to be able to handle different measures, such as percentages, currencies etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are looking for is called a loss function, something like
$$ \mathcal{L} = \sum_i f(y_i, \hat{y}_i)$$
with $y$ - true value, $\hat{y}$ - guess.

Unfortunately, there is no simple advice on choosing the best loss function for every case. Many statistical devices use a quadratic loss function, aka sum of squares or $\ell_2$ norm:
$$ \mathcal{L} = \sum_i (y_i - \hat{y}_i)^2 $$
This function is sensitive to outliers, though, so one big miss will lead to large overall loss. If you do not want that, a more robust measure would be $\ell_1$ norm:
$$ \mathcal{L} = \sum_i |y_i - \hat{y}_i| $$
There is also $\ell_0$ norm, which only counts the total number of correct guesses, and treats any miss equally. You might want to use that for discrete outcomes.

Anyway, my point is that choosing a specific loss function depends mostly on what you are trying to achieve from what data. Without any field-specific knowledge, I would likely default to sum of squares.